# How can I save the .svg output from an interactive() display with a "Save As" prompt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am an artist trying to wrap my head around generative/procedural design using NumPy and various assorted tools in jupyter notebook.

I have some code https://github.com/GreySoulX/Circle-generator/blob/main/BrokenCircles.ipynb (see below) that will generate a number of concentric circles of random radius and output them as SVG code. I can get it to display, and I can even get the SVG output with the basic code, but when put it all in a functions and call it with interactive() my saved files come out empty rather that what is shown in my notebook with widgets.VBox() .

Where can I fix this? Am I just missing this by a million miles?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, Markdown, clear_output
from ipywidgets import widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual, interactive, Button
```

```
def make_circles(n_circles=100,min_radius=0.05, max_radius=9.0, debug=False, Refresh=False ):

    x_bounds = [-10, 10]
    y_bounds = [-10, 10]
    circles = []

    for i in range(n_circles):
        c = np.array([0, 0])
        r = np.unique(np.sort(np.round(np.random.uniform(min_radius,max_radius,1),2)))
        circles.append((c, r))
    
    circles
    circle_patches = []
    for c, r in circles:
        circle_patches.append(mpatches.Circle(c, r, fill=None, edgecolor='black'))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))
 
    if not debug:
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.axis('off')

    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(x_bounds)
    ax.set_ylim(y_bounds)

    collection = PatchCollection(circle_patches, match_original=True)
    ax.add_collection(collection)

    return fig, ax
    
w = interactive(make_circles,
                n_circles=(1,300,1),
                min_radius=(0.00, 2.0, 0.1),
                max_radius=(2.0, 20, 0.5))

#------Button----------
button = widgets.Button(description='Save as...')
out = widgets.Output()

def on_button_clicked(_):
    #link function with output
    with out:
        #what happens when we hit button
        #clear_output()
        print('Saving Files...')
        plt.savefig('SomeFile.svg', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
        plt.savefig('SomeFile.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)


# linking button and function together using a button's method
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
# displaying Circles and button
widgets.VBox([button,out,w])
#------End Button------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's happening

This is an issue with how the inline backend handles closing figures and what `plt.savefig` does internally. The way static figures are displayed in notebooks (i.e. when not using [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#ipympl)) is that at the end of cell execution (or in this case at the end of the callback from the slider) the current figure is closed and displayed.

However `plt.savefig` expects there to be a currently open figure as it calls `plt.gcf` (get current figure) internally which either grabs the most recently active figure or creates a new empty figure if no figures are active.

So when you did this not in functions the figure wasn't closed until the cell was finished executing and so `plt.savefig` was able to find the figure. However when you moved to functions it was no longer able to find the current figure.

There are two basic solutions to this.

## Solutions

### 1. Global `fig`

You can lift figure to the global scope and use `fig.savefig` - this makes sure that both the plot updating method and the saving method are refering to the same `fig`.

```py
def make_circles(n_circles=100,min_radius=0.05, max_radius=9.0, debug=False, Refresh=False ):
    global fig
    ...
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ....

def on_button_clicked(_):
    global fig
    ...
        fig.savefig('SomeFile.svg', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

### 2 - interactive backend

Use one of the interactive backends such as `%matplotlib qt` or `%matplotlib ipympl`. If you are working in a notebook or jupyterlab then i'd recommend ipympl which you can install with `pip install ipympl`.

With these backends the same closing of the figure does not automatically happen, so you can structure your code like this:

```py
%matplotlib ipympl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def make_circles(n_circles=100,min_radius=0.05, max_radius=9.0, debug=False, Refresh=False ):
    ax.cla() # clear all the artists off the axes
    ...
    # use the same axes for `add_collection`

def on_button_clicked(_):
    # you can now use `plt.savefig` but I would still recommend using `fig.savefig`
```